# How can I populate the partial view using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I populate the partial view using jQuery? The result: nothing is happening when clicking the link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.block').click(function () {
            var id = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Link/Link",
                data: { Letter: id },
                success: function (mydata) {
                    var dom = $(mydata);
                    $("#link").empty().append(dom);
                },
                type: "POST"
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>  

<a href="<%=Url.Action("Link",new {Letter="A"}) %>" id="A" class="block">A</a>
<a href="<%=Url.Action("Link",new {Letter="B"}) %>" id="B" class="block">B</a>

<div id="link">
  <% Html.RenderPartial("LinkUC", ViewData["Letter"]); %>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Link(string Letter)
{
    ViewData["Letter"] = LinkManagementRepository.GetAllOrganizationLinks(Letter);

    return PartialView("LinkUC",ViewData["Letter"] );  
}
```

Comment: @mazher, have you checked the value returned by server (`mydata` variable)? A simple alert would tell if you are getting the correct html or not from server.

Comment: Have you looked with FireBug?

Comment: the thing is that the method Link/link is called but it doesn't return anything

Comment: Have you debugged and made sure your Action is actually returning something? Does a 500 error come up in firebug?

Answer (score 1):

What on earth is this:

```
return PartialView("LinkUC",ViewData["Letter"] );
```

Why not using strongly typed views instead:

```
public ActionResult Link(string letter)
{
    var model = LinkManagementRepository.GetAllOrganizationLinks(letter);
    return PartialView("LinkUC", model);
}
```

Get rid of this `ViewData` plague.

Comment: Don't you know? This is a conglomerate of weak and strong type view. :) Even though this is not an answer to his question still a +1 from me for @mazhar to not do such a horrible thing. **EVER**.

Answer (score 0):

what does LinkManagementRepository.GetAllOrganizationLinks(Letter)?  I don't think you need to set the ViewData but return the repostiroy call directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Point it towards an action that returns a `PartialViewResult`, so the HTML in the response will be loaded into the wrapped set you call it on.

e.g. `$('div#link).load('yourPartialViewResultAction', {Letter: id }, null);`